# How to access Javascript object in HTML using angular js?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i have a JS object like this:

```
var some_object = {
    "1":{"name":"test","type_name":"test_type"},
    "2":{"name":"test2","type_name":"test_type2"}
};
```

currently am try to access value of `'type_name'` at `index 1` in html like this:

```
<label><span>{{ some_object[1]['type_name'] }} </span></label>
```

but it gives me error. can anyone help that how to access it in html using angular?

Comment: first you need to kept inside `$scope` then only you can access like so.

Comment: Can you provide the clear angularjs code?

Comment: share your angularjs controller and `some_object` area too ?

Comment: define your object using the array syntax like this: var some_object_array = [{"name":"test","type_name":"test_type"},{"name":"test2","type_name":"test_type2"} ];  Then you access the array items like this: some_object_array[0].name

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Inside your angularjs controller:-

```
$scope.some_object = {
    "1":{"name":"test","type_name":"test_type"},
    "2":{"name":"test2","type_name":"test_type2"}
};
```

and in the view file

```
<label><span>{{ some_object[1].name }} </span></label>
```

Then using the **some_object** you can access in HTML view.

For basic understanding you follow the below example:-

HTML file:

```
<body ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="simpleController">
    <strong>First name:</strong> {{firstName}}<br />
    </div>
</body>
```

AngularJS Controller:

```
var simpleController = function ($scope){
    $scope.firstName = "Your Name";
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var some_object = {
    "1":{"name":"test","type_name":"test_type"},
    "2":{"name":"test2","type_name":"test_type2"}
};

$scope.some_obj = some_object;
```

And you can access it

```
<label><span>{{ some_obj[1].type_name }} </span></label>
```

OR

```
$scope.some_object = {
    "1":{"name":"test","type_name":"test_type"},
    "2":{"name":"test2","type_name":"test_type2"}
};
```

And you can access it

```
<label><span>{{ some_object[1].type_name }} </span></label>
```

because if its in `$scope` then only it will be accessible the way you want.

> But for this you will require JSON data

Regards

Comment: it's giving me syntax error that "{{ or {% expected"

Comment: Please check my updated answer. You will have to access its property with `.` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Assign it to some scope value of angular js

$scope.value=some_object;

and in html

```
<label><span>{{ value.1.type_name}} </span></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign someObject to the scope

```
$scope.some_object = {
    "1":{"name":"test","type_name":"test_type"},
    "2":{"name":"test2","type_name":"test_type2"}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing it like this.

```
some_object[1].type_name
```

or if you are unable to render it in html, you can store it in a $scope property and render it.

```
$scope.typeName = some_object[1].type_name
```

In Html

```
<span>{{typeName}}</span>
```

Hope it helped.